getting longUploadsUnspecified when try to get channel status from youtube api
Im developing livestraming app with expo,
and I need to check user's youtube channel if he can streaming live to youtube,
from youtube api docu: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels
I should get status.longUploadsStatus that need to return:

Valid values for this property are:
allowed – This channel can upload videos that are more than 15 minutes long.
disallowed – This channel is not able or eligible to upload videos that are more than 15 minutes long. A channel is only eligible to upload long videos if it is in good standing based on YouTube Community Guidelines and it does not have any worldwide Content ID blocks on its content.

the problem I have is that every channel the status.longUploadsStatus return longUploadsUnspecified, In youtube docu there is nothing mention that,
There is another option to know if youtube channel can live or any idea to get the valid property of status.longUploadsStatus?
I tried to use this api code:
axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels', {
  params: {
    key: API_KEY,
    id: 'CHANNEL_ID',
    part: 'status',
  },
})
.then(response => {
  console.log('API Response:', JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('API Error:', error);
});

and I get this response for status:

"status":{"privacyStatus":"public","isLinked":true,"longUploadsStatus":"longUploadsUnspecified","madeForKids":false}

And I'm expecting to get "longUploadsStatus":"allowed/disallowed/eligible "
Any Ideas?
